# If a circle's area gets increased at the rate of 2 $cm^2. s^{-1}$ .Then what will be the increase rate of it's radius after $\frac{28}{11}$ seconds?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If a circle's area gets increased at the rate of 2  $cm^2. s^{-1}$ .Then what will be the increase rate of it's radius after $\frac{28}{11}$ seconds?

My Try : $\frac{ds}{dt}= 2\pi r \frac{dr}{dt}$ so we can write $2\pi r \frac{dr}{dt} = 2$. Can anyone help me out with this problem?

Comment: What dimension of the circle is being increased? (and the rate needs to be per second).

Comment: @MRobinson   I think the OP is referring to increase in area. Also, I have corrected the unit (edit pending review).

Comment: @DevashishKaushik of course, I hadn't noticed the $cm^2$! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your way is correct indeed we have

$$A(t)=\pi r(t)^2\implies A'(t)=2 \pi r(t)r'(t)=2 \implies r'(t)=\frac1{\pi r(t)}$$

and therefore

$$\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac1{\pi r} \implies rdr=\frac 1 \pi dt \implies \frac12r^2=\frac t \pi+C \implies r(t)=\sqrt{\frac{2t}\pi+C}$$

and assuming $r(0)=r_0 \implies C=r_0^2$ that is

> $$r'(t)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi t+\pi r_0^2}}$$

Comment: @gimsu   The OP had asked for increase rate $dr/dt$ of the radius , not the radius itself. It might be norw useful to point out that he just had to plug in the given values in the expression he reached, instead of repeating the calculation and finding the radius. ( No offence intended ) :-)

Comment: @DevashishKaushik I get your point but as you can see the rate $r'(t)$ depends upon $r(t)$ therefore we need to find $r(t)$ to solve the problem completely. For example assuming $r(0)=0$ we can explicitely find a value for the rate at $t=28/11 s$.

Comment: Of course, I was referring to the fact that seeing that the OP reached ${dr\over dt} = f(R)$ , it might be better to give him a slight hint instead of the succeeding steps in their entirety. I am sorry if it seemed like I was suggesting that your solution was incorrect.

Comment: @DevashishKaushik I didn't have that idea about your kind observation. Thanks

Comment: I think  $r(0) = r_0$@gimusi

Comment: @cmi Oh yes of course! I fix that, Thanks.